# Automatic background changer using Python 2.7.3 not working, though it should

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, python-2.7, gnome

I'm very new to Ubuntu/Python/Bash/Gnome in general, so I still feel like there's a chance I'm doing something wrong, but it's been 3 days now without success...

Here's what the script is supposed to do:
* [✓] Download 1 random image from wallbase.cc
* [✓] Save it to the same directory that the script is running from
* [x] Set it as the wallpaper

There are two attempts made to set the wallpaper two using different commands and NEITHER work when in the script. There is a print statement (2nd line from the bottom) that spits out the correct terminal command because I can C&P the print result and it works fine, it just doesn't work when it's executed in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import os
from gi.repository import Gio

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://wallbase.cc/random/12/eqeq/1366x768/0.000/100/32")
page_source = response.read()
thlink_pos = page_source.find("ico-X")
address_start = (page_source.find("href=\"", thlink_pos) + 6)
address_end = page_source.find("\"", address_start + 1)

response = urllib2.urlopen(page_source[address_start:address_end])
page_source = response.read()

bigwall_pos = page_source.find("bigwall")
address_start = (page_source.find("src=\"", bigwall_pos) + 5)
address_end = page_source.find("\"", address_start + 1)

address = page_source[address_start:address_end]

slash_pos = address.rfind("/") + 1

pic_name = address[slash_pos:]

bashCommand = "wget " + page_source[address_start:address_end]
os.system(bashCommand)

print "Does my new image exists?", os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "/" + pic_name)

#attempt 1
settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.background")
settings.set_string("picture-uri", "file://" + os.getcwd() + "/" + pic_name)
settings.apply()

#attempt 2
bashCommand = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://" + os.getcwd() + "/" + pic_name
print bashCommand
os.system(bashCommand)
settings.apply()
```

Answer (score 2):

You've successfully changed your settings, but they're still left unapplied, try next:

```
settings.apply()
```

after setting "picture-uri" string.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Though I never tried that command specifically, I researched about gsettings.sync() from the gsettings site, to no avail. I've also edited the above script adding your command to it in the way that doesn't work for me. I put it after both attempts, just in case.

Comment: @MALON That's quite strange, this code works fine for me. What version of Ubuntu and gnome do you use? (I use Ubuntu 12.04). Another thing, try to check if you set a valid value for 'picture-uri'.

Comment: I'm actually using Unity. Not sure what gnome version is installed, but I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 x86. I am using Gsettings because it works when issuing the commands separately. This is the post that told me to use Gsettings (though I am not OP in that thread): http://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity

Comment: Works for me too, also on 12.04.  [Well, if by "works" you mean brought up a first-gen Pokémon background..]

Comment: " Another thing, try to check if you set a valid value for 'picture-uri'" Well, if I issue the command gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background it spits out the correct results if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @MALON, are you using Unity or Unity-2D?

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko echo $DESKTOP_SESSION reveals "ubuntu" which I believe means 3d

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko I figured it out. All you guys were saying it was working for you but not me....yet I ran the same settings as you guys. So I thought "What else BESIDES the script could be different"? Then it clicked. Sudo. I was sudoing it, which was probably trying to change the background for the user "root" and not myself. Thank you for settings.appy() though, pretty sure that helped because yesterday I was trying without sudo and it was failing then as well. So the key was "don't use sudo" and "use settings.apply()" Thanks so much man!

Comment: @MALON: could you post your comment as an answer and accept it. For the benefit of future readers from google to find the solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (Ubuntu 12.04).

I've modified your script (unrelated to your error):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Set desktop background using random images from http://wallbase.cc

It uses `gi.repository.Gio.Settings` to set the background.
"""
import functools
import itertools
import logging
import os
import posixpath
import random
import re
import sys
import time
import urllib
import urllib2
import urlparse
from collections import namedtuple

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ sudo apt-get install python-bs4
from gi.repository.Gio import Settings  # pylint: disable=F0401,E0611

DEFAULT_IMAGE_DIR = os.path.expanduser('~/Pictures/backgrounds')
HTMLPAGE_SIZE_MAX = 1 << 20  # bytes
TIMEOUT_MIN = 300  # seconds
TIMEOUT_DELTA = 30  # jitter

# "Anime/Manga", "Wallpapers/General", "High Resolution Images"
CATEGORY_W, CATEGORY_WG, CATEGORY_HR = range(1, 4)
PURITY_SFW, PURITY_SKETCHY, PURITY_NSFW, PURITY_DEFAULT = 4, 2, 1, 0
DAY_IN_SECONDS = 86400


UrlRetreiveResult = namedtuple('UrlRetreiveResult', "path headers")


def set_background(image_path, check_exist=True):
    """Change desktop background to image pointed by `image_path`.

    """
    if check_exist:  # make sure we can read it (at this time)
        with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
            f.read(1)

    # prepare uri
    path = os.path.abspath(image_path)
    if isinstance(path, unicode):  # quote() doesn't like unicode
        path = path.encode('utf-8')
    uri = 'file://' + urllib.quote(path)

    # change background
    bg_setting = Settings.new('org.gnome.desktop.background')
    bg_setting.set_string('picture-uri', uri)
    bg_setting.apply()


def url2filename(url):
    """Return basename corresponding to url.

    >>> url2filename('http://example.com/path/to/file?opt=1')
    'file'
    """
    urlpath = urlparse.urlsplit(url).path  # pylint: disable=E1103
    basename = posixpath.basename(urllib.unquote(urlpath))
    if os.path.basename(basename) != basename:
        raise ValueError  # refuse 'dir%5Cbasename.ext' on Windows
    return basename


def download(url, dirpath, extensions=True, filename=None):
    """Download url to dirpath.

    Use basename of the url path as a filename.
    Create destination directory if necessary.

    Use `extensions` to require the file to have an extension or any
    of in a given sequence of extensions.

    Return (path, headers) on success.
    Don't retrieve url if path exists (headers are None in this case).
    """
    if not os.path.isdir(dirpath):
        os.makedirs(dirpath)
        logging.info('created directory %s', dirpath)

    # get filename from the url
    filename = url2filename(url) if filename is None else filename
    if os.path.basename(filename) != filename:
        logging.critical('filename must not have path separator in it "%s"',
                         filename)
        return

    if extensions:
        # require the file to have an extension
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if root and len(ext) > 1:
            # require the extension to be in the list
            try:
                it = iter(extensions)
            except TypeError:
                pass
            else:
                if ext not in it:
                    logging.warn(("file extension is not in the list"
                                  " url=%s"
                                  " extensions=%s"),
                                 url, extensions)
                    return
        else:
            logging.warn("file has no extension url=%s", url)
            return

    # download file
    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
    logging.info("%s\n%s", url, path)
    if os.path.exists(path):  # don't retrieve if path exists
        logging.info('path exists')
        return UrlRetreiveResult(path, None)
    try:
        return UrlRetreiveResult(*urllib.urlretrieve(url, path,
                                                     _print_download_status))
    except IOError:
        logging.warn('failed to download {url} -> {path}'.format(
            url=url, path=path))


def _print_download_status(block_count, block_size, total_size):
    logging.debug('%10s bytes of %s', block_count * block_size, total_size)


def min_time_between_calls(min_delay):
    """Enforce minimum time delay between calls."""
    def decorator(func):
        lastcall = [None]  # emulate nonlocal keyword

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if lastcall[0] is not None:
                delay = time.time() - lastcall[0]
                if delay < min_delay:
                    _sleep(min_delay - delay)
            lastcall[0] = time.time()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@min_time_between_calls(5)
def _makesoup(url):
    try:
        logging.info(vars(url) if isinstance(url, urllib2.Request) else url)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(HTMLPAGE_SIZE_MAX))
        return soup
    except (IOError, OSError) as e:
        logging.warn('failed to return soup for %s, error: %s',
                     getattr(url, 'get_full_url', lambda: url)(), e)


class WallbaseImages:
    """Given parameters it provides image urls to download."""

    def __init__(self,
                 categories=None,  # default; sequence of CATEGORY_*
                 resolution_exactly=True,  # False means 'at least'
                 resolution=None,  # all; (width, height)
                 aspect_ratios=None,  # all; sequence eg, [(5,4),(16,9)]
                 purity=PURITY_DEFAULT,  # combine with |
                 thumbs_per_page=None,  # default; an integer
                 ):
        """See usage below."""
        self.categories = categories
        self.resolution_exactly = resolution_exactly
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.aspect_ratios = aspect_ratios
        self.purity = purity
        self.thumbs_per_page = thumbs_per_page

    def _as_request(self):
        """Create a urllib2.Request() using given parameters."""
        # make url
        if self.categories is not None:
            categories = "".join(str(n) for n in (2, 1, 3)
                                 if n in self.categories)
        else:  # default
            categories = "0"

        if self.resolution_exactly:
            at_least_or_exactly_resolution = "eqeq"
        else:
            at_least_or_exactly_resolution = "gteq"

        if self.resolution is not None:
            resolution = "{width:d}x{height:d}".format(
                width=self.resolution[0], height=self.resolution[1])
        else:
            resolution = "0x0"

        if self.aspect_ratios is not None:
            aspect_ratios = "+".join("%.2f" % (w / float(h),)
                                     for w, h in self.aspect_ratios)
        else:  # default
            aspect_ratios = "0"

        purity = "{0:03b}".format(self.purity)
        thumbs = 20 if self.thumbs_per_page is None else self.thumbs_per_page
        url = ("http://wallbase.cc/random/"
               "{categories}/"
               "{at_least_or_exactly_resolution}/{resolution}/"
               "{aspect_ratios}/"
               "{purity}/{thumbs:d}").format(**locals())
        logging.info(url)
        # make post data
        data = urllib.urlencode(dict(query='', board=categories, nsfw=purity,
                                     res=resolution,
                                     res_opt=at_least_or_exactly_resolution,
                                     aspect=aspect_ratios,
                                     thpp=thumbs))
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        return req

    def __iter__(self):
        """Yield background image urls."""
        # find links to bigwall pages
        # css-like: #thumbs div[class="thumb"] \
        #      a[class~="thlink" and href^="http://"]
        soup = _makesoup(self._as_request())
        if not soup:
            logging.warn("can't retrieve the main page")
            return
        thumbs_soup = soup.find(id="thumbs")
        for thumb in thumbs_soup.find_all('div', {'class': "thumb"}):
            bigwall_a = thumb.find('a', {'class': "thlink",
                                         'href': re.compile(r"^http://")})
            if bigwall_a is None:
                logging.warn("can't find thlink link")
                continue  # try the next thumb

            # find image url on the bigwall page
            # css-like: #bigwall > img[alt and src^="http://"]
            bigwall_soup = _makesoup(bigwall_a['href'])
            if bigwall_soup is not None:
                bigwall = bigwall_soup.find(id='bigwall')
                if bigwall is not None:
                    img = bigwall.find('img',
                                       src=re.compile(r"(?i)^http://.*\.jpg$"),
                                       alt=True)
                    if img is not None:
                        url = img['src']
                        filename = url2filename(url)
                        if filename.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
                            yield url, filename  # successfully found image url
                        else:
                            logging.warn('suspicious url "%s"', url)
                        continue
            logging.warn("can't parse bigwall page")


def main():
    level = logging.INFO
    if '-d' in sys.argv:
        sys.argv.remove('-d')
        level = logging.DEBUG
    # configure logging
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s %(message)s',
                        level=level, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        backgrounds_dir = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        backgrounds_dir = DEFAULT_IMAGE_DIR

    # infinite loop: Press Ctrl+C to interrupt it
    #NOTE: here's some arbitrary logic: modify for you needs e.g., break
    # after the first image found
    timeout = TIMEOUT_MIN  # seconds
    for i in itertools.cycle(xrange(timeout, DAY_IN_SECONDS)):
        found = False
        try:
            for url, filename in WallbaseImages(
                    categories=[CATEGORY_WG, CATEGORY_HR, CATEGORY_W],
                    purity=PURITY_SFW,
                    thumbs_per_page=60):
                res = download(url, backgrounds_dir, extensions=('.jpg',),
                               filename=filename)
                if res and res.path:
                    found = True
                    set_background(res.path)
                # don't hammer the site
                timeout = max(TIMEOUT_MIN, i % DAY_IN_SECONDS)
                _sleep(random.randint(timeout, timeout + TIMEOUT_DELTA))
        except Exception:  # pylint: disable=W0703
            logging.exception('unexpected error')
            _sleep(timeout)
        else:
            if not found:
                logging.error('failed to retrieve any images')
                _sleep(timeout)
        timeout = (timeout * 2) % DAY_IN_SECONDS


def _sleep(timeout):
    """Add logging to time.sleep() call."""
    logging.debug('sleep for %s seconds', timeout)
    time.sleep(timeout)


main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried to implement a python script that used the PIL library to write text on an  image then update the Gnome background "picture-uri" to point to that image using the Gio class.  The python script would ping pong between two images to always modify the one not in use and then attempt to "switch" by updating the Settings.  Did this to avoid any flicker as modifying the current background directly drops it out temporarily.  While in the shell and calling the script directly I rarely saw any issue, but in the cronjob it simply wouldn't update on the pong. I used both sync and apply and would wait several minutes before trying to switch the images.  Didn't work.  Tried cron as user (su -c "cmd" user) and that didn't work either.

Finally gave up on the ping pong approach when I noticed that Gnome will detect any change in the background file and update.  So dropped the ping pong method and went to a temp file that I just copy over the current background using the shutil library.  Works like a charm.